# Xcode error: Command /Developer/usr/bin/clang++ failed with exit code 1 due to duplicate symbol

Tags: xcode, arrays, duplicate-symbol

I'm trying to write a program in C++ which runs Conway's Game of Life. I think I have everything that I need, but I'm having some trouble with compiling.

The program is composed of four files: `gameoflife.h`, a header file which contains my global constants and function declarations, `gameoflife.cpp`, which defines the functions, `main.cpp`, which uses the functions, and `seeds.cpp`, which contains a list of predefined seeds to be used.

When I go to compile the application, I seem to have a clash of duplicate symbols between `main.cpp` and `gameoflife.cpp` over an array called `currGen` which is declared in `gameoflife.h`.

Both `main.cpp` and `gameoflife.cpp` include `gameoflife.h`, which of course is necessary so that they have access to the global constants and function declarations.

The exact error I receive is the following:

```
duplicate symbol _currGen in /(same_path)/ConwaysGameOfLife.build/Objects-normal/
x86_64/gameoflife.o and
/(same_path)/ConwaysGameOfLife.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
for architecture x86_64
Command /Developer/usr/bin/clang++ failed with exit code 1
```

I've looked around on Stack Overflow but haven't found anything which matches my problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably defining the variable `currGen` in your header file, not just declaring it.

There needs to be exactly one definition, in one .cpp file. The .h file should just declare it, using `extern`.

[This answer goes into much more detail.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1433387/1218876)